# file_get_contents remove include header files from a C program

Tags: php, url

There is a C program file hosted on github and I am trying to get its content using php from its raw file url. 
This is the code that I am using currently.

```
<?php
$x = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiteshGarg/codingeek/master/Data-Structure/Queue/PriorityQueue.c");
echo $x;
?>
```

This is able to fetch file but it removes `<stdio.h> and <stdlib.h>` and consider them as HTML tags when try to render themby appending their closing tag like -

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

//Other CODE in FILE 

</stdlib.h></stdio.h>
```

I have tried it using curl as well but no luck.

```
$curl = curl_init('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiteshGarg/codingeek/master/Data-Structure/Queue/PriorityQueue.c');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$x = curl_exec($curl);
echo $x;
```

Is there any way to show this as it is?

**EDIT -**
The real scenario is that I am using Wordpress and I have to embed this code inside a code highlighter. For that, I have added a shortcode but this is displaying additional HTML tags in the code displayed on the webpage. So I don't have to use echo or print in the real scenario rather I have to get a plain text and merge it in the existing post.

Comment: `$curl = curl_init('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiteshGarg/codingeek/master/Data-Structure/Queue/PriorityQueue.c');
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$x = curl_exec($curl);
print($x);`

Comment: you should edit your question to better reflect the problem you **actually have** - especially don't leave out the part where you don't echo the text, but merge it with other. or the part where you use wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after you disclosed the scenario, the solution would be instead to escape HTML-sequences, so that your wordpress doesn't automatically close tags anymore.

```
<?php
$x = file_get_contents("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/HiteshGarg/codingeek/master/Data-Structure/Queue/PriorityQueue.c");
echo htmlentities($x);
?>
```

(edit: removed old answer from before)

Comment: then what exactly is the issue? neither file_get_contents nor curl strip HTML-tags from what they are to read

Comment: @HiteshGarg  use `print` instead of `echo`

Comment: @Anant how should print do anything different?

Comment: Actually the real scenario is that i am using wordpress and I have to embed this code inside a code highlighter and for that I have added a shortcode but this is displaying additional html tags in the code. So I don't have to use echo or print I have to get a plain text and merge it in the existing post.

Comment: ah. **now** we are getting somewhere. that's a completely different scenario.